# How to execute that in 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have 2 tables `customer` and `orders`:

**customers**:

```
| custID | Name  | Age |
|--------|-------|-----|
| 1      | Peter | 23  |
| 2      | Julie | 34  |
| 3      | Tom   | 45  |
```

**orders**:

```
| custID | product | color |
|--------|---------|-------|
| 1      | shirt   | blue  |
| 1      | jacket  | black |
| 2      | jacket  | green |
| 3      | hat     | grey  |
| 3      | shirt   | white |
```

I now want to get all customers and their orders, ordered as a list. So something like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [name] => Peter
            [age] => 23
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product] => shirt
                            [color] => blue
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product] => jacket
                            [color] => black
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [name] => Julie
            [age] => 34
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product] => jacket
                            [color] => green
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [name] => Tom
            [age] => 45
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product] => hat
                            [color] => grey
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product] => shirt
                            [color] => white
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

When I do:

```
SELECT name, age, product, color
FROM `customers`, `orders`
where `customers`.`id` = `orders`.id
group by name
```

I get:

```
| name  | age | product | color |
|-------|-----|---------|-------|
| Peter | 23  | jacket  | green |
| Julie | 34  | shirt   | blue  |
| Tom   | 45  | hat     | grey  |
```

Is this even possible with only one query?

Comment: Does the `orders` table have its own `id` in addition to a `custID`?  It looks like you are joining on that column which seems incorrect.

Comment: @dana: No, there is no additional column.

Comment: Any output produced by a single query can only look tabular - two dimensional, with no further complexities / splitting in between. Array within an array makes it table inside a table and that is not doable using a query. If you have a single tabular structure in mind, that can be achieved. Or, maybe you could have customer name and age against each product and let the program iterating through the returned records detect when there's a change in customer id.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
JOIN orders
USING custID
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY custID ASC;
```

Comment: I get this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'custID
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY custID ASC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of steps here...

First, you should run the following query:

```
SELECT
    `customers`.`id`,
    `customers`.`name`,
    `customers`.`age`,
    `orders`.`product`,
    `orders`.`color`
FROM `customers`, `orders`
where `customers`.`id` = `orders`.`id`
order by `customers`.`id`
```

Which should give you de-normalized tabular data that looks something like this:

```
$array = array(
    array("id" => 1, "name" => "Peter", "age" => 23, "product" => "shirt", "color" => "blue"),
    array("id" => 1, "name" => "Peter", "age" => 23, "product" => "jacket", "color" => "black"),
    array("id" => 2, "name" => "Julie", "age" => 34, "product" => "jacket", "color" => "green"),
    array("id" => 3, "name" => "Tom", "age" => 45, "product" => "hat", "color" => "grey"),
    array("id" => 3, "name" => "Tom", "age" => 45, "product" => "shirt", "color" => "white")
  );
```

You can then transform the that data into your desired format as follows:

```
$transformed = array();
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($array)) {
    $id = $array[$i]["id"];
    $name = $array[$i]["name"];
    $age = $array[$i]["age"];
    $products = array();
    while ($i < count($array) && $id == $array[$i]["id"]) {
        array_push($products, array("product" => $array[$i]["product"], "color" => $array[$i]["color"]));
        $i++;
    }
    array_push($transformed, array("id" => $id, "name" => $name, "age" => $age, "products" => $products));
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fe856e1f71f699e84215b6f66d25589f71e255e

Answer (score 0):

i think you should user INNER JOIN:

`SELECT * FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN orders AS o ON c.custID = o.custID GROUP BY c.custID ORDER BY c.custID ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to achieve the desired outcome with single query. With the first query get the list of customers. Then perform a second query, which will load all the orders for the customers from the first query. And in a loop match orders to respective customers.

EDIT: something like this

```
$result = [];
$customers = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `customers`")->fetchAll();
foreach ($customers as $c) {
  $result[$c['id']] = $c;
}

$orders = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `custID` IN (".implode(', ', array_keys($result).")");
foreach ($orders as $o) {
  if (!isset($result[$o['custId']]['orders']))
    $result[$o['custId']]['orders'] = [];
  $result[$o['custId']]['orders'][] = $o;
}
```

Comment: The point of making just one query is avoiding various transactions being opened and then closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql `SELECT name, age, product, color FROM`customers`,`orders`where`customers`.`id`=`orders`.id group by name` is fine, just add the customer id and order id also in the sql. Then, in PHP, as you iterate the result set, populate the customer info first (id, name, age) with customer id as the key and name, age as value as an array. Likewise, populate the order for that customer in the key 'orders' with the order id as key and value as an array (product, color).

Once you have the array populated, iterate over that array and keep putting things into a new array since the output you want is an array with sequential keys (0, 1, 2 etc) instead of customer id.

```
$initialList = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(!array_key_exists($row['customer_id'], $initialList)) {
       $initialList[$row['customer_id']] = array(
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'age' => $row['age'],
            'orders' => array()
       );
    }
    $initialList[$row['customer_id']]['orders'][] = array(
            'product' => $row['product'],
            'color' => $row['color']
    );
}

$finalList = array();
foreach($initialList as $customerId => $customer) {
    $customer['ID'] = $customerId;
    $finalList[] = $customer;
}

//to print and check the array
print_r($finalList);
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the PHP part? I'm not sure how to link the 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT c.custID,c.name, c.age, group_concat(CONCAT_WS(':',o.product,o.color)SEPARATOR ',') as productos
FROM customers AS c 
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON c.custID = o.custID 
GROUP BY c.custID;
```

You just have to parse the products.

```
    $array=array();
    while($r = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
       $id=$row['custID'];
       $name=$row['name'];
       $age=$row['age'];
       $productos=$row['productos'];
       $productsSeparats = explode(',',$productos);
       $orders=array();
       foreach ($productsSeparats as $value) {
          $ar=explode(':',$value); 
           array_push($orders, array("product" => $ar[0], "color" => $ar[1]));
       }
        array_push($array, array("id" => $id, "name" => $name, "age" => $age, "orders" => $orders));

            }
```